# ${D} variable in install command

Tags: compiling, yocto

I have seen the following install command used in multiple yocto recipes

```
install -d ${D}${libdir}
```

I am aware of the install command and its purpose, however I am unable to understand the purpose of ${D} variable as it is often nowhere defined in the recipe. Can somebody explain the purpose of this shell variable?

Comment: Check out the [OpenEmbedded User Manual](http://docs.openembedded.org/usermanual/usermanual.html#id323670) *D: The destination directory*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `${D}` variable allows the software being built to be installed in a directory other than its real target. For example, you might configure the software so that `libdir` is `/usr/lib`, but that's for the target device; when you run the installation on your build system, you don't want the newly-built files to actually be installed in `/usr/lib`, you want the placed somewhere isolated so that they can be readily identified and copied across to the target system. So you create a temporary directory and install there:

```
mkdir /tmp/yocto-target
make install D=/tmp/yocto-target
```

That way the files end up in `/tmp/yocto-target/usr/lib` and so on. You can then archive all of `/tmp/yocto-target` using whatever tool you prefer, dropping the `/tmp/yocto-target` prefix, copy the archive to the target device and install its contents there.

In other build systems, the `DESTDIR` variable is used for the same reason.

Comment: Does installing package in ${D}${libdir}  copy the output to package DESTDIR or to rootfs  foder in /tmp/work.../rootfs ?

Comment: Umm... I’m not sure what you’re asking; installing in `${D}${libdir}` installs in whatever directory the `D` and `libdir` variables point to. `DESTDIR` is used in other build systems, not Yocto’s.

Comment: The answer explains the "purpose" of ${D}, but as the OP wrote "it is often nowhere defined in the recipe".  It still remains a mystery where its value comes from.  E.g. I have a template recipe generated by the petalinux-create command which references ${D} but there is no "include" or any other clue as to where the ${D} is defined.

Comment: @2.718 it’s not defined because it’s up to the user to specify its value, as indicated in my example: `make install D=/tmp/yocto-target` will install to a set of directories rooted in `/tmp/yocto-target`. If no value is given, the installation is done in `/`.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt thanks for the clarification.  It is not obvious to a newcomer who has not written BB recipes before and is only looking at them to understand how it all hangs together.

Answer (score 6):

`${D}` is the usual top of the path used by a Yocto recipe where the recipe installs files that belong to packages produced by this recipe. These directories under `${D}` are scanned by the build system for files to include into packages (like RPM files) and to be included in the so-called sysroot tree where files (e.g. libraries and headers) go that are used by other packages. There are some default rules for this scan and the rules can be expanded.
It is recommended to use these Yocto default paths under `${D}` as much as possible to benefit from the built-in mechanisms of Yocto.

`${libdir}` is defined in bitbake.conf by default as: `${exec_prefix}/lib` which is `/usr/lib` by default, defined in the same file.

```
install -d ${D}${libdir}
```

In the end this "install" shell command just creates a directory where files are to be saved (e.g. by do_install) that should finally be installed under `/usr/lib` on the target.

`${D}/a/b/c` for file `c` is just the intermediate path used for Yocto packaging and `${D}` is "cut away" when the same file `c` is on the target filesystem.
So for instance `${D}/a/b/c` will be at `/a/b/c` on the target.

`${D}` is defined by default in [poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n365) as:

```
TMPDIR = "${TOPDIR}/tmp"
BASE_WORKDIR ?= "${TMPDIR}/work"
WORKDIR = "${BASE_WORKDIR}/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR}"
D = "${WORKDIR}/image"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with yocto; does this `D` variable come into play, given [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339466/117549)?